Approximation of $\mathrm{TREES}(3)$
Define $\mathrm{TREES}(n)$ as count of all valid trees in definition of $\mathrm{TREE(n)}$, not necessarily a longest one. E.g. $\mathrm{TREES}(2) = |{1,2,1\ 2,2\ 1,1\ 22\ 2,2\ 11\ 1,1\ 22,2\ 11}| = 8$.
Obviously, $\mathrm{TREES}(3)$ is on same layer of big number with $\mathrm{TREE}(3)$. Can we get a more approximative expression of $\mathrm{TREES}(3)$ using $\mathrm{TREE}(3)$ ?

And what is the definition of $\text{TREE}(n)$?

@PaulSinclair hyperlink included

Fix an integer $n \geqslant 2$ corresponding to your finite number of colors. Clearly, all subsequence of a valid sequence of trees is valid. Moreover, any valid sequence is injective, thus all its subsequences are distinct. Therefore, for all valid sequence of lenth $l$, we can build $2^l - 1$ distinct valid sequences (when I see your example with $n = 2$, I suppose that you don't consider the empty sequence to be true). In particular, since by definition, there is a sequence of lenth $\mathrm{TREE}(n)$, your can build at least $2^{\mathrm{TREE}(n)} - 1$ valid sequences hence,
$$
\mathrm{TREES}(n) \geqslant 2^{\mathrm{TREE}(n)} - 1.
$$
Reciprocally, consider a valid sequence $s$ of lenth $l$. Of course, $l \leqslant \mathrm{TREE}(n)$. Let $1 \leqslant k \leqslant l$ and $i$ the number of vertices of $s_k$. By definition of valid sequences, we must have $i \leqslant k$. It gives at most $r(i)$ possibilities for the underlying uncolored tree, where $r(i)$ is the number of rooted unlabeled trees with $i$ verticies. It is obviously bounded by Cayley's formula by $i^{i - 2}$ when $i \geqslant 2$ and we have Otter's asymptotic formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)) $r(i) \sim D\alpha^ii^{-3/2}$ when $i \rightarrow +\infty$ for some constants $D \approx 0.44$ and $\alpha \approx 2.96$.
Moreover, the vertices of $s_k$ has to be labeled with the set of colors that contains $n$ elements giving a total of at most $n^ir(i)$ possibilities. Since $i \leqslant k$, we have at most $n^kr(k)$ possibilities independently of $i$ and since $l \leqslant \mathrm{TREE}(n)$, we have the following (very unsharp) bound,
$$
\mathrm{TREES}(n) \leqslant \prod_{k = 1}^{\mathrm{TREE}(n)} n^kr(k),
$$
with the informal approximation,
$$
\prod_{k = 1}^{\mathrm{TREE}(n)} n^kr(k) \approx \prod_{k = 1}^{\mathrm{TREE}(n)} D(\alpha n)^kk^{-3/2} = D^{\mathrm{TREE}(n)}(\alpha n)^{\mathrm{TREE}(n)(\mathrm{TREE}(n) + 1)/2}(\mathrm{TREE}(n)!)^{-3/2}.
$$

Rough but at least a beginning (for the problem, maybe not for the post)
